# Is there any function that i could use to test if an array contains any symbols in ASCII?

Tags: java, arrays, validation

I have a program that tests for symbols within a array of characters. i have been using the Charterer.is...() function to test to find characters but i cant find a function like that for symbols. Is there a function that lets me do this or would i have to program it myself?

I am programming in Java by the way.

Comment: What kinds of symbols are you referring to, exactly?

Comment: any symbols within askii that includes anything that is not a number or a alphabetic letter

Comment: Do you know of a way to test a *single* character?

Comment: Do you mean *ASCII*?

Comment: yes, i have been using the function charecter.is..(). it can test for lower and uppercase chars and numbers but not any symbols

Comment: yes i mean ASKII,a function for UNICODE  would also be good

Comment: I think you mean ASCII.

Comment: Can't you test `!Character.isAlphabetic(c) && !Character.isDigit(c)`?

Comment: yes, thanks that works :)

Answer (score 0):

Unicode characters have individual attributes, exist in exactly one block and exist in exactly one basic category (categories can be hierarchal, such as letters, uppercase letters, lowercase letters).

"Being ASCII" is none of those but all of the characters in ASCII are incorporated into Unicode as the [C0 Controls and Basic Latin](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) block.

So, your test becomes

```
Character.UnicodeBlock.of(c) == Character.UnicodeBlock.BASIC_LATIN && 
!Character.isAlphabetic(c) && 
!Character.isDigit(c)
```